# Delete Command is missing from right click context menu?

Tags: windows-7

To update window, I converted my `pen drive` into bootable. But now when i want to delete it,  I right click on a folder,the Delete option is missing from it.So how can I put it back? This is on a Windows 7 system.

[image: See the Image]

[image: Folder Properties Image]

Comment: For every Folder is it missing for only for this specific folder?

Comment: specific folder (inside removable disk)

Comment: What type of folder is that "BOOT"?

Comment: yes, it is a boot folder

Comment: Please add every details regarding your removable disk as well as what type of files/folder it has inside it. It will be more easy to find solution and maybe only for that particular folder this option is not showing. If the whole removable disk contains useless folders then try to format it.

Comment: Can you go to properties of the folder and send screenshots?

Comment: Are you able to clear the folder using Command Prompt?

`rd "<drive:\folderpath>" /s`

Comment: Using clear command or format D:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Command Prompt window and use the following syntax to delete a folder and sub-folders along with all the files in them:

`rd "<drive:\folderpath>" /s`

For example, if the folder path is E:\Boot, to delete it you'd use:

`rd E:\Boot /s`

If the folder path contains spaces, you need to enclose the path within double-quotes.

Comment: Error occur `The Media is Write Protected`

Comment: Try: http://ccm.net/faq/4214-how-to-disable-write-protection-from-a-usb-key. and https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-remove-write-protection-from-usb-drive/6778/3